# Regarding cronjob execution time

Tags: linux, unix, cron

I am having list of cron job functions.Each function run for certain period of time.Is there any way to find how long each cron function execute,Like time of start executing function and end time?

```
Expected output:

Cron tab start time: timestamp
cront tab end time: timestamp
```

Answer (score 0):

Read [crontab(5)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/crontab.5.html). A cron job is just a shell command or script. That shell could, for example, use [logger(1)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/logger.1.html) mixed with [date(1)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/date.1.html) and [time(1)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/time.1.html). See also [time(7)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/time.7.html). See also [GNU bash](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/) documentation.

A cron job could also be a [GUILE](https://www.gnu.org/software/guile/guile.html) script, or a [Python](https://python.org/) one. See [execve(2)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/execve.2.html), [fork(2)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/fork.2.html) and other [syscalls(2)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/syscalls.2.html) which is called by `crond`

And  [`cron`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cron) is [open source](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Open_source), so you are allowed to study its source code.... (e.g. of [GNU mcron](https://www.gnu.org/software/mcron/)). Or use [strace(1)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/strace.1.html) on it to understand its behavior.

Consider reading [*Advanced Linux Programming*](https://mentorembedded.github.io/advancedlinuxprogramming/) and see [Linux From Scratch](https://linuxfromscratch.org/).

For example, I am running thru cron a backup script starting with

```
#!/bin/bash
cd $HOME
renice -n +2 -p $$
ionice -c Best-effort -n +5 -p $$
tm=$(date +"backup-home+%Y-%b-%d-%Hh%M")
logger --id=$$ -t backup-home start $tm
sync
```